# How to add multiple classNames on a react component

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using creat-react-app's webpack settings, which uses babel to make a unique css classnames.
If there's a child component B inside a component A,
and B returns :

```
<div className={styles.B1} />
```

and A returns :

```
<div>
    <B className={styles.B2}/>
</div>
```

I want to put both classnames B1, B2, but only B1 works.

Comment: Or, you can use the npm package called classnames

Answer (score 6):

Both classNames inside component B like this

```
<div className={ `${styles.B1} ${styles.B2}` } />
```

should work.

Or if you want to pass the className from props from component A, then

```
<div className={ `${styles.B2} ${this.props.className}` } />
```

Answer (score 2):

In Component `A`, pass in the required classes as `className`

```
const styles = {
  B1: "styleClassB1",
  B2: "styleClassB2",        
}

// inside return
<div>
  <B className={`${styles.B2} ${styles.B1}`}/>
</div>
```

In Component `B`, use the passed-in `className` prop

```
<div className={this.props.className} />
```